# Open subset of irreducible component is open in whole space if it doens't meet any other irreducible component.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $U$ be open subset of irreducible component $Z$.
> Then show that if $U$ doesn't meet any other irreducible component, then $U$ is open in whole space $X$

---

[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889187/open-subscheme-of-an-irreducible-component-remains-open) is the same question but the answer is not for me.

[Question and my try]

I solve this under condition " $X$ has a finitely many irreducible component".

For example, If $x \notin U$ be any element of $X$, then $x$ is in $Z_x$ , where $Z_x$ is an irreducible component  which is not $Z$.

If we denote $U = O \;\cap \;Z$ for  some open set $O$ in $X$ , then $U = O \;-\; \cup_{x}Z_x $.

Since the union is **finite** union ,  $\cup_{x}Z_x $ is closed set so $U$ is open in $X$.

However, If we don't have condition " $X$ has a finitely many irreducible component" , how can we show this now?

Thank you for your attention.

---

[Conclusion]

Now, I realize that this is a false statement. That is, The answer of [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889187/open-subscheme-of-an-irreducible-component-remains-open) is also not true.
**Why are you closing this question without even reading this carefully?**
Some people voted to 'closed', deleted their comments and ran away..

[Answer to my question]

There is a counter-example.
Consider the real number $\mathbb{R}$ which has a usual topology. Then every irreducible component is a singleton set. This is because $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff. Then , any singleton set $\{ a \}$ is an open set of itself $\{ a \}$ and disjoint with all another irreducible components. However, $\{ a \}$ is not an open set of whole space $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Keen-ameteur That link is exactly what I said above in "here"  hyperlink.

Comment: What is an irreducible component of $X$ ?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma , A topological space $X$ is ''reducible'' if it can be written as a union $X = X_1 \cup X_2$ of two closed proper subsets $X_1$ , $X_2$ of $X$.
A topological space is ''irreducible'' if it is not reducible. Also, "The irreducible component" means a maximal set along these irreducible sets.

Comment: @Leucippus , Again, That link is exactly what I said above in "here" hyperlink. There is no answer about the proof of direction which I want. That link just said "by basic topology, it is true". Also, since that is an old question link , I make this new question